# Как проверить установлена ли программа в Windows?

Tags: c#, windows

Как проверить установлена ли та или иная программа в Windows?

Например для того чтобы запускать установку драйвера только в случае его отсутствия или для индикации в интерфейсе.

Comment: Эм... Так программы или драйверы? Драйвера могут быть установлены в ручную без инсталяторов.

Comment: @Vasek в моем случае цель была - запускать инсталлеры драйверов устройств в случае если установка ещё не производилась, поэтому это присутствует в формулировке

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант через проверку записей в реестре:

```
public static bool IsSoftwareInstalled(string name)
{
    bool result = false;

    CheckRegistry(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
    if (!result) CheckRegistry(@"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");

    void CheckRegistry(string path)
    {
        using (var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path))
        {
            if (key == null) return;
            foreach (var subkey_name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                using (var subkey = key.OpenSubKey(subkey_name))
                {
                    if (subkey != null && subkey.GetValue("DisplayName")?.ToString() == name)
                    {
                        result = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    return result
}
```

Вариант с использованием ManagmentObjectSearcher, работает гораздо медленней:

```
public static bool IsSoftwareInstalled(string name)
{
    bool result = false;

    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", String.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE Caption = '{0}'", name));

    foreach (var item in searcher.Get())
    {
        var software = (ManagementObject)item;    
        if (software["Caption"]?.ToString() == name)    
        {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```